# Column assigned into a pd.DataFrame is duplicated in another pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following peace of code:

```
predictions_dict['AE'] = predictions_df
errors_dict['AE'] = (train_with_nan_df.iloc[1:] - predictions_dict['AE'])
errors_dict['AE']['MSE'] = np.nanmean(np.power(errors_dict['AE'], 2), axis=1)
```

I am using dictionaries to store the predictions and errors from some different models. When I run the peace of code below, I get that both **errors_dict['AE']['MSE']** and **predictions_dict['AE']['MSE']** have values assigned, when that should be only the case for **errors_dict**.

As additional information I, the original **predictions_df** shows no MSE entry, as expected. Could you explain the logic inside python making that happens? and how to solve it?

I tried using .copy() with the same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, I had defined the dictionaries as follow:

```
errors_dict = predictions_dict = dict()
```

I thought that it created 2 independent empty dictionaries, but it doesn't seem this way. I just changed it to:

```
errors_dict = dict()
predictions_dict = dict()
```